# xml download - blocked

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am trying to download xml file from one polish website. For first days it worked but then I could download this file to my server (but I can open and download it on my computer). In file on my server in which there should be xml content is html content telling me that I have been blocked.

I was trying to contact with webmaster from website from which I want to get xml and he told me that I am not blocked by IP address. So the question is what I should sent in headers or what to download this file?

My code to download xml file is below and here is the xml which I want to download: http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml

```
$headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
$headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch";
$headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
$headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
$headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

$xml_data = file_get_contents($xml,false,stream_context_create(
    array("http" => array('header' => $headers)))); // your file is in the string "$xml" now.
file_put_contents($xml_md5, $xml_data); // now your xml file is saved.
```

Request the URL in verbose mode (-v):

```
* About to connect() to www.polskatimes.pl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 195.8.99.38... connected
* Connectede to www.polskatimes.pl (195.8.99.38) port 80 (#0)
> GET /rss/fakty_kraj.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15 libssh2/1.2.6
> Host: www.polskatimes.pl
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 10:40:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: close
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Expires: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 10:40:15 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
(html page with message that I am temporary blocked)
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: what happens if you hit the url yourself? or from (say) wget on the server's command line? are you sure you need all those headers and a plain `$xml = file_get_contents($url)` won't work just as well?

Comment: the same happens when I am using wget or enter url into lynx, so the problem is to get file from server. In begging I wasn't using all those headers but when this problem has started I was looking here for the answer and I found that the problem can be with headers but with them it doesnt work too.

Comment: and the same url works fine from another machine? any proxies/filters in between the server and this site that could be rejecting the request at all? Or if the filtering's not by IP, do you have to log into this site somehow to get the data?

Comment: yes, it works fine from my workstation. there arent any proxies/filters between the server and this site. I havent got acces to log from this site.

Answer (score 2):

To inspect what happens behind the scene (and which headers you actually need or not) you need to analyze a little. That is nothing magic, you can do it on the commandline with a software called *curl*. It is available for many (even all?) computer platforms.

First step most often is to request the URL in verbose mode (`-v`):

```
$ curl -v http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml
* About to connect() to www.polskatimes.pl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 195.8.99.38... connected
* Connected to www.polskatimes.pl (195.8.99.38) port 80 (#0)
> GET /rss/fakty_kraj.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: www.polskatimes.pl
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2013 17:39:51 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: sprawdz_cookie=1; expires=Thu, 17-Apr-2014 17:39:51 GMT
< Location: http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml?cookie=1
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-2
<
* Closing connection #0
```

That shows you the request (prefixed with *>*) and response (prefixed with *<*) headers and the response body (empty in this case). As you can see the status is *302 Found* which means as 3xx a redirect and the location header tells where to:

```
Location: http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml?cookie=1
```

As the query parameter suggests, this is a cookie-check. The cookie itself is set as well:

```
Set-Cookie: sprawdz_cookie=1; expires=Thu, 17-Apr-2014 17:39:51 GMT
```

So in the next step we will replay the last command but this time setting the cookie which can be done with the `-b` argument:

```
$ curl -v -b prawdz_cookie=1 http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml
* About to connect() to www.polskatimes.pl port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 195.8.99.38... connected
* Connected to www.polskatimes.pl (195.8.99.38) port 80 (#0)
> GET /rss/fakty_kraj.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: www.polskatimes.pl
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: prawdz_cookie=1
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2013 17:43:52 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: sesja_gratka=e38fa0eb93705c8de7ae906198494439; expires=Wed, 24-Apr-2013 17:43:52 GMT; path=/; domain=polskatimes.pl
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title><![CDATA[Fakty - Kraj]]></title>
    <link>http://www.polskatimes.pl/fakty/kraj/</link>
    <atom:link href="http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <description><![CDATA[Materia┼éy z dzia┼éu Kraj]]></description>
... (cutted)
```

So this is immediately successful. And now the real good part: You know that you need to set the cookie for the request *and* curl shows you already all headers it used:

```
> GET /rss/fakty_kraj.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: www.polskatimes.pl
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: prawdz_cookie=1
```

Most of them you do not need to care about with `file_get_contents`, the first line as well as the *Host:* and the *Accept:* line.

The *User-Agent:* header does not look like it really plays a role as curl is accepted.

So all what is left is the *Cookie:* header. Let's try in PHP:

```
$ php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml', null, 
stream_context_create(['http'=>['header'=>['Cookie: prawdz_cookie=1']]]));"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <title><![CDATA[Fakty - Kraj]]></title>
    <link>http://www.polskatimes.pl/fakty/kraj/</link>
    <atom:link href="http://www.polskatimes.pl/rss/fakty_kraj.xml" rel="self" 
    type="application/rss+xml"/>
...  (cutted)
```

And this is the direct test that only the *Set-Cookie: prawdz_cookie=1* header is needed.

Comment: thanks hakre for this as this looks very good, but unfortunatelly it doesn't help me as my server still cannot download this file

Comment: So which response do you get in your shell with curl? You should follow what I outline in the answer step by step so you start to understand what is going on behind the scenes. I've also put all output in the answer so you can compare how it behaved here and how it behaves with your computer.

Comment: I have added to my question response from curl on my server. The strange thing is this that in yours response you have got status 302 and server Apache and in mine there is status 200 and server nginx and still html page with information that I am temporary blocked.

Comment: Yeah, okay, then you are blocked. As you can see the request itself is not very different than mine, so I would say your IP *is* blocked. What is also interesting is that your response is comming from Nginx while mine is served by Apache. The temporary blocked might be a hint that something triggered so the block is temporary only. Also I wonder why they put a 200 OK for a blocking message. It obviously is not the content. From the request alone there is not much more to say. I could try to provoke this on my end if you like but that won't help you either. Maybe you used it too often?

Comment: I was using it often (every 10 min) as I want to check if there is something new in this XML and if yes then insert into my database. So I was using it very often but from about 2 weeks I wasn't using it and I am still blocked. What is more people from this site told me that my IP address is not blocked.

Comment: Yes I've already read yesterday that you asked them, however the response tells you there is some blocking. Probably they use some service they don't know about so look in the wrong place. I would try with requesting from a different IP address as another test.